# What is the difference between removeProp and removeAttr in JQuery 1.6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you removeProp on something you should have used `removeAttr()` on will it silently fail? Will it work? Will it actually remove the entire attribute or just the value inside it?

If `checked` is added using `removeProp()`, can it be removed with `removeAttr()`?

Many questions!

Comment: Are these not the sort of questions you could answer yourself by writing 5-10 lines of jQuery and observing the results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An attribute of an element is something like 'class'. Whereas its property would be 'className'.

This is the reason for adding jQuery.prop and jQuery.propHooks into version 1.6, to make it easier working with both.

So if the the property had the same name as the attribute you could use both removeProp or removeAttr.

I asked a similar question on jQuery forum, got this answer:

> Yes, attr is meant for html attributes
>   as they are strictly defined.  prop is
>   for properties.  So for instance, say
>   you have a node elem with class
>   "something" (raw element not jQuery
>   object).  elem.className is the
>   property, but  is where the
>   attribute resides.  Changing the class
>   attribute also changes the property
>   automatically and vise versa. 
>   Currently, attr is jumbled and
>   confusing because it has tried to the
>   job of both functions and there are
>   many bugs because of that.  The
>   introduction of jQuery.fn.prop will
>   solve several blockers, separate code
>   as it should have been separated from
>   the beginning, and give developers
>   faster functions to do what they
>   expect them to do.  Let me make up a
>   percentage for a sec and say that from
>   my experience in the support IRC and
>   reading other's code, 95% of the use
>   cases for attr will not have to switch
>   to prop.

**EDIT**

It may be best to stick to using either jQuery.attr or jQuery.prop. Theres seems to be some strange behaviour when setting and removing the checked attribute using both.

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/uTCJF/

There is a bug in 1.6 to do with selected: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9079

Answer (score 9):

The [official jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/) provides a very clear explanation:

> In the 1.6 release we’ve split apart
>   the handling of DOM attributes and DOM
>   properties into separate methods. The
>   new .prop() method sets or gets
>   properties on DOM elements, and
>   .removeProp() removes properties. In
>   the past, jQuery has not drawn a clear
>   line between properties and
>   attributes. Generally, DOM attributes
>   represent the state of DOM information
>   as retrieved from the document, such
>   as the value attribute in the markup
>   . DOM
>   properties represent the dynamic state
>   of the document; for example if the
>   user clicks in the input element above
>   and types def the `.prop("value")` is
>   abcdef but the `.attr("value")` remains
>   abc.
>
> In most cases, the browser treats the
>   attribute value as the starting value
>   for the property, but Boolean
>   attributes such as checked or disabled
>   have unusual semantics.
>
> For example, consider the markup
>   `<input type="checkbox" checked>`. The
>   presence of the checked attribute
>   means that the DOM `.checked` property
>   is true, even though the attribute
>   does not have a value. In the code
>   above, the checked attribute value is
>   an empty string (or `undefined` if no
>   attribute was specified) but the
>   checked property value is `true`.
>
> Before jQuery 1.6, `.attr("checked")`
>   returned the Boolean property value
>   (`true`) but as of jQuery 1.6 it returns
>   the actual value of the attribute (an
>   empty string), which doesn’t change
>   when the user clicks the checkbox to
>   change its state.
>
> There are several alternatives for
>   checking the currently-checked state
>   of a checkbox. The best and most
>   performant is to use the DOM property
>   directly, as in `this.checked` inside an
>   event handler when this references the
>   element that was clicked. In code that
>   uses jQuery 1.6 or newer, the new
>   method `$(this).prop("checked")`
>   retrieves the same value as
>   `this.checked` and is relatively fast.
>   Finally, the expression
>   `$(this).is(":checked")` works for all
>   versions of jQuery.

Comment: Hehe I was just reading that. That explains the strange behaviour here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/uTCJF/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery 1.6, I was was trying to clone a menu item which had several `id` attributes, and so I did this:

`$('ul.menu').clone().filter('*').removeProp('id').appendTo('.sidebar');`

When I inspected the elements in Firebug I had a lot of `id="undefined"` - not what I wanted. So  now I am using `removeAttr` and it seems to work much better.

`$('ul.menu').clone().filter('*').removeAttr('id').appendTo('.sidebar');`