# Active disabled textare when check a specific radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I need that, once a specific radio input has been checked, a text area, normally disabled, return active.

I've used the jquery click(function) and removeProp but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using jquery 3.4.0, popper 1.14.7 and the latest version of bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FormInputTextArea">Inserire Eventuali informazioni aggiuntive</label>
                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="FormInputTextArea" rows="1" disabled></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Radios - Aggiornamento numero fila -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="UpdateLineNumb" name="groupOfDefaultRadios">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="UpdateLineNumb">Aggiornamento numero fila</label>
        </div>

        <!-- Radios - Invio messaggio -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="SendMessageCheck" name="groupOfDefaultRadios">

          <label class="custom-control-label" for="SendMessageCheck">Invio messaggio</label>
        </div>


$('input[id="SendMessageCheck"]').click(function(){
    $('textarea[id="FormInputTextArea"]').removeProp('disabled');
})
```

I expect that when clicked the radios `id="SendMessageCheck"`   `name="groupOfDefaultRadios"` the disabled option on textarea `name="message"` `id="FormInputTextArea"` should disappera. Noting happen instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input[id="SendMessageCheck"]').click(function(){
    $('textarea[id="FormInputTextArea"]').removeAttr('disabled');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FormInputTextArea">Inserire Eventuali informazioni aggiuntive</label>
                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="FormInputTextArea" rows="1" disabled></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Radios - Aggiornamento numero fila -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="UpdateLineNumb" name="groupOfDefaultRadios">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="UpdateLineNumb">Aggiornamento numero fila</label>
        </div>

        <!-- Radios - Invio messaggio -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="SendMessageCheck" name="groupOfDefaultRadios">

          <label class="custom-control-label" for="SendMessageCheck">Invio messaggio</label>
        </div>
```

Use `removeAttr()`. Check[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894229/what-is-the-difference-between-removeprop-and-removeattr-in-jquery-1-6)for more information about `removeAttr()` vs.`removeProp()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use `removeAttr()` instead of `removeProp()`

```
$('textarea[id="FormInputTextArea"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```